# ESPRIMA error with Aurelia-auth in Aurelia 1

Tags: aurelia, esprima, aurelia-auth

I'm trying to convert an Aurelia project and have run into a problem. I installed aurelia-auth and configured it in the aurelia.json file as:

    `{
       "name": "aurelia-auth",
       "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-auth/src",
        "main": "aurelia-auth"
    }`

When I try to run the app using the au-cli I get a series of errors like this:

`commonJs.convert: COULD NOT CONVERT: C:/Development/UCCSS/aurelia-v1-   uccss/node_modules/aurelia-auth/src/aurelia-auth.js, so skipping it. Error was: Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
    { uid: 10,
      name: 'writeBundles',
      branch: false,
      error:
       { [Error: Parse error using esprima for file: C:/Development/UCCSS/aurelia-v1-uccss/node_modules/aurelia-auth/src/aurelia-auth.js
       Error: Line 1: Unexpected token]
       moduleTree: [ 'config/routerConfig' ],
       fileName: 'C:/Development/UCCSS/aurelia-v1-uccss/src/config/routerConfig.js' },
      duration: [ 0, 925164337 ],
      time: 1470156183228 }`

Is it possible that aurelia-auth was broken with the latest release of Aurelia or is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by changing the config to:

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-auth",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-auth/dist/amd",
  "main": "aurelia-auth"
}
```